# Necessity of Coherence for Interference in the Context of Indistinguishable Photon Paths

Tags: optics, double-slit-experiment, coherence

I've been studying the interference phenomena observed in the double-slit experiment and came across a concept that piqued my interest. It is well understood that for interference patterns to form, the overlapping waves (or photons) must exhibit a degree of coherence. However, the underlying quantum mechanics introduce the principle of indistinguishability, where photons are considered indistinguishable when their paths overlap in a manner that leaves their origins untraceable.

Given this, how does the necessity of coherence interplay with the concept of indistinguishability of photon paths in producing observable interference patterns? Is coherence a requirement because it ensures the indistinguishability of photon paths, or are there additional subtleties at play regarding how coherence influences the formation of interference patterns?

Furthermore, how do temporal and spatial coherence relate to the quantum mechanical description of light as indistinguishable paths that contribute to interference?

**Edit:**
Thanks to many, this post has good explanations. However I want to further ask some questions to understand the question on hand more deeply.

One explanation that is in an educational article by [Mendel](https://opg.optica.org/view_article.cfm?pdfKey=f2548ad6-8597-4f5e-8c906d2b360296a5_10905) recommended through comments. In this article, it explains that coherence is connected to the indistinguishability of paths through the density matrix, and I am convinced by it. However, my current question is about how the indistinguishability of paths is connected to the indistinguishability of particles through the wave function. I'm confused at this part because although it can be explained by the density matrix, I believe it should also be explained by the indistinguishability of particles through the wave function since interference is 'local' and it's a form of the interference of wave functions. If not, please correct me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

The double slit involves a single photon that has 2 groups of paths, each group associated with a slit. I say groups, because a single slit leads to diffraction, which involves integrating over the whole slit (single diffraction is the limit of two (half-sized) slit interference with zero separation.

But let's just say two paths for simplicity: each slit is a path, and the photon can take both, so it does, if the difference of the path lengths is less than the coherence length of the light source.

That's really all there is to it, and a classical description is fine (except of course, the energy coming in quanta--otherwise a classical description is fine).

The indistinguishability involves two photons and doesn't apply to YDSE. It applies to things like:

$$ e^++e^-\rightarrow \gamma_1 + \gamma_2 $$

interfering (in phase) with:

$$ e^++e^-\rightarrow \gamma_2 + \gamma_1 $$

Meanwhile, in Møller scattering ($t$-channel):
$$ e_1^-+e_2^-\rightarrow e^-_1 + e^-_2 $$

interferes totally out of phase with ($u$-channel)
$$ e_1^-+e_2^-\rightarrow e^-_2 + e^-_1 $$

(Note: in the electron version of the YDSE, we don't subtract the amplitudes for each slit, we still add them).

Nevertheless, two photon interference may be more demonstrative of your concerns. See [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hong–Ou–Mandel_effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hong%E2%80%93Ou%E2%80%93Mandel_effect)

Comment: Can you also explain if indistinguishability applies when there are 2 photons, how it comes in to pllay in quantum eraser experiment?

Comment: @HakanAkgün that's really a separate question, a an answer worth anything wouldn't fit in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

For the DSE spatial coherence matters where as temporal does not.  In any light experiment the EM field is the king, the photons just follow where they are directed to go. Per Dirac, Feynman and many others each photon takes its own path.

In the DSE the EM field is already affected by the excited electron in the atom even before the photon is created/transmitted ... the EM field sees 2 slits .... the photon just goes thru one slit.

Temporal coherence implies that phase is important but it is not ... photons do not cancel each other ... they are independent of each other. There are no photons in the dark bands, all photons go to the bright bands.  You can calculate the pattern with Huygen's principle or use the more advanced Feynman path integral.

Indistinguishability is not so relevant here (we don't care which photon went where) but yes we do want the photons as similar as possible. A good setup for the DSE will use a small directed source (i.e. laser) and where the photons are very similar (i.e. laser color) ... this will give the sharpest pattern.  Well designed slits also help.

Comment: I mean indistinguishability of path for example in quantum eraser. And it's relavent in this context surely. Can you explian in this regard

Comment: The eraser expt has a lot of confusion any many bad explanations, FTL is not possible.  In general even the DSE is explained with very old principles (like photons cancelling) ... these old principles are still used today ... and can be misleading. In the eraser any starting photon will be guided by the EM field to take either interference path or not .... they use "coincidence detector" to tell.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially coherence and indistinguishability are two sides of the same coin (seems like you already figured this). One can see this by observing that measuring the path of a photon induce decoherence since the detector has to interact with the photon and add fluctuations/noise that destroy the interference pattern. The relationship, or tradeoff, between how much can we know (in this context distinguish) and how much we have to disturb the system, i.e. decohere it, is rather deep and general.

BTW, I understood your questions as referring to indistinguishable paths (of the same photon). If your interest is more regarding indistinguishable photons, it is a more subtle issue.

Comment: Yes I meant indistinguishable paths but doesn't it eventually correspond to indistinguishable of photons

Comment: Not necessarily. You can send a single photon and split it to two paths. Then the question of  indistinguishable photons never comes up since there is only one photon. If you insist on sending two photons then you should probably specify what is the question.